# JasperReports: Grouping Report Elements

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have ran into 2 situations already that *feel* like they could be solved if JasperReports had some kind of `JRDesignElementGroup`. I've checked the `net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.` package high and low but can't find anything like it, although I was able to find a [`JRDesignGroup`](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/design/JRDesignGroup.html) which looks like it *sort of* accomplishes what I'm looking for, but I'm not very sure of that.

Here are the siutations where my issue is cropping up:

**(1) Grouping multiple text fields together:**
I'd like to have a report where I can print out the names and values of a bunch of metrics; something that looks like:

```
Name: John Smith
Email: john.smith@example.com
```

I was hoping to accomplish this by creating 1 `JRDesignElement` subclass instance, and adding it to a band in my `JasperDesign` object. However, after thinking it over, that setup requires 3 separate `JRDesignElement`s: 2 `JRDesignTextField`s (for the metric name and value) and 1 `JRDesignStaticText` for the colon (":") and space between them.

Is there a way to append these 3 items to a group and then just add the group to a band?

**(2) Group an image and its title/caption**
I also would like to do the same as above, except using `JRDesignImage` and `JRDesignStaticText` elements, where the image is an image to be displayed on my report, and the static text will be a title or caption to be placed above the image.

Is there any way to append these 2 items to a group and then just add the group to a band?

If so, can anyone provide JRXML, or even more preferably, some Java examples for how to do this appending? And if not, what's the solution/work-around?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not used to using the JR api directly, but in a JRXML file, you may assign the following expression to a textfield : $F{name} + " : " + $F{value}.

Comment: Thanks JB! But then, what's the difference between a TextField's expression (like the example you provided), and a TextField's text? (JRDesignTextField has both setExpression and setText methods.)

Comment: In http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/design/JRDesignTextField.html, there is no setText method.

Comment: Good point ;-) I was thinking of JRDesignStaticText. Any ideas about the image title/caption?

Comment: I think you'll indeed need two elements to do that.

Comment: It seems like you're trying to avoid creating the .jrxml ahead of time. Instead you want to generate it. Is that true? Why? (Sometimes that's needed... but most times it isn't.)  Also: "Text Fields" are always more useful than "Static Text" elements. (OK, there's surely a counter-example somewhere... but it's nearly always true.)

Comment: Regarding the image & caption: is it sufficient to just have an image with a Text Field above it or below it? Why is the concept of "grouping" them together needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> (1) Grouping multiple text fields together:

- The first solution - using single `JRDesignTextField` element

```java
    //Detail
    band = new JRDesignBand();
    band.setHeight(40);

    textField = new JRDesignTextField();
    textField.setX(0);
    textField.setY(0);
    textField.setWidth(200);
    textField.setHeight(40);
    textField.setHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignEnum.LEFT);
    textField.setStyle(normalStyle);
    textField.setMarkup(JRCommonText.MARKUP_HTML);
    expression = new JRDesignExpression();
    expression.setText("\"<b>Name:   </b>\" + $F{Name} + \"<br/><b>Email: </b>\" + $F{Email}");
    textField.setExpression(expression);
    textField.getLineBox().getLeftPen().setLineWidth(1);
    textField.getLineBox().getTopPen().setLineWidth(1);
    textField.getLineBox().getRightPen().setLineWidth(1);
    textField.getLineBox().setLeftPadding(10);
    band.addElement(textField);

    ((JRDesignSection) jasperDesign.getDetailSection()).addBand(band);
```

- The second solution - using two `JRDesignStaticText` and two `JRDesignTextField` elements together

```java
    //Detail
    band = new JRDesignBand();
    band.setHeight(40);

    JRDesignStaticText staticText = new JRDesignStaticText();
    staticText.setX(0);
    staticText.setY(0);
    staticText.setWidth(60);
    staticText.setHeight(20);
    staticText.setMode(ModeEnum.OPAQUE);
    staticText.setHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignEnum.LEFT);
    staticText.setStyle(boldStyle);
    staticText.setText("Name: ");
    staticText.getLineBox().getLeftPen().setLineWidth(1);
    staticText.getLineBox().getTopPen().setLineWidth(1);
    staticText.getLineBox().setLeftPadding(10);
    band.addElement(staticText);

    textField = new JRDesignTextField();
    textField.setX(60);
    textField.setY(0);
    textField.setWidth(200);
    textField.setHeight(20);
    textField.setHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignEnum.LEFT);
    textField.setStyle(normalStyle);
    expression = new JRDesignExpression();
    expression.setText("$F{Name}");
    textField.setExpression(expression);
    textField.getLineBox().getTopPen().setLineWidth(1);
    textField.getLineBox().getRightPen().setLineWidth(1);
    textField.getLineBox().setLeftPadding(10);
    band.addElement(textField);

    staticText = new JRDesignStaticText();
    staticText.setX(0);
    staticText.setY(20);
    staticText.setWidth(60);
    staticText.setHeight(20);
    staticText.setMode(ModeEnum.OPAQUE);
    staticText.setHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignEnum.LEFT);
    staticText.setStyle(boldStyle);
    staticText.setText("Email: ");
    staticText.getLineBox().getLeftPen().setLineWidth(1);
    staticText.getLineBox().getBottomPen().setLineWidth(1);
    staticText.getLineBox().setLeftPadding(10);
    band.addElement(staticText);

    textField = new JRDesignTextField();
    textField.setStretchWithOverflow(true);
    textField.setX(60);
    textField.setY(20);
    textField.setWidth(200);
    textField.setHeight(20);
    textField.setPositionType(PositionTypeEnum.FLOAT);
    textField.setStyle(normalStyle);
    expression = new JRDesignExpression();
    expression.setText("$F{Email}");
    textField.setExpression(expression);
    textField.getLineBox().getRightPen().setLineWidth(1);
    textField.getLineBox().getBottomPen().setLineWidth(1);
    textField.getLineBox().setLeftPadding(10);
    band.addElement(textField);

    ((JRDesignSection) jasperDesign.getDetailSection()).addBand(band);
```

> (2) Group an image and its title/caption

Using three `JRDesignImage` and single `JRDesignStaticText` elements

```java
    band = new JRDesignBand();
    band.setHeight(110);

    String imgPath1 = "\"jasperreports.png\"";
    String imgPath2 = "\"js_logo.png\"";
    int img1Width = 105;
    int img2Width = 200;
    int distance = 20;

    expression = new JRDesignExpression();
    expression.setText(imgPath1);

    JRDesignImage image = new JRDesignImage(jasperDesign);
    image.setX(0);
    image.setY(0);
    image.setWidth(img1Width);
    image.setHeight(26);
    image.setScaleImage(ScaleImageEnum.FILL_FRAME);
    image.setExpression(expression);

    band.addElement(image);

    expression = new JRDesignExpression();
    expression.setText(imgPath2);

    image = new JRDesignImage(jasperDesign);
    image.setX(distance + img1Width);
    image.setY(0);
    image.setWidth(img2Width);
    image.setHeight(87);
    image.setScaleImage(ScaleImageEnum.FILL_FRAME);
    image.setExpression(expression);

    band.addElement(image);

    expression = new JRDesignExpression();
    expression.setText(imgPath1);

    image = new JRDesignImage(jasperDesign);
    image.setX(2*distance + img1Width + img2Width);
    image.setY(0);
    image.setWidth(img1Width);
    image.setHeight(26);
    image.setScaleImage(ScaleImageEnum.FILL_FRAME);
    image.setExpression(expression);

    band.addElement(image);

    JRDesignStaticText staticText = new JRDesignStaticText();
    staticText.setX(200);
    staticText.setY(90);
    staticText.setWidth(60);
    staticText.setHeight(20);
    staticText.setMode(ModeEnum.OPAQUE);
    staticText.setHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignEnum.LEFT);
    staticText.setStyle(boldStyle);
    staticText.setText("The title above images");

    band.addElement(staticText);

    ((JRDesignSection) jasperDesign.getDetailSection()).addBand(band);
```

Comment: Once again, thank you so much for the extremely helpful and thoughtful answer!